# SQL query join- unrelated tables

Tags: sql

Can someone help me to join the two tables without any primary or secondary keys. Sample table is

TABLE 1

```
| ID | NAME |
|  1 | x    |
|  2 | Y    |
|  3 | z    |
```

TABLE 2

```
| Num | NAME | DATE      |
| 52  | X    | 12-aug-17 |
| 53  | X    | 11-apr-17 |
| 62  | X    | 10-aug-11 |
| 12  | y    | 2-jan-16  |
| 23  | Y    | 3-apr-18  |
```

I want retrieve data from X

```
select * 
from table2 
where name = 'x';

| Num | NAME | DATE      |
| 52  | X    | 12-aug-17 |
| 53  | X    | 11-apr-17 |
| 62  | X    | 10-aug-11 |
```

Now I will get three data from table2. I'm little stuck after this step. I want to get top of data the from table 2 and combine with table one.

I want final output should be

```
| ID | NAME | Num | DATE      |
| 1  | x    | 52  | 12-aug-17 |
```

Can someone suggest me how can I join this table? Its easy to join when we have any primary key but here not the case

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? mysql <> sql server. Feel free to add the tag for your DBMS.

Comment: What did you mean by "get top of data from table 2"? How much row do you need (`1` row or all row with value of `12-aug-17` which is max date?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  The code is for different dbms.

Comment: "Related" <> "Has keys" Your tables are related by the column `Name`, even though you haven't made that column a key value on either table. You can have a relational database composed entirely of heaps. It'll just be a really poorly performing relational database, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the maximum `DATE` using a subquery, as in:

```
select t1.id, t2.*
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
  where t2.date = (
    select max(date) from table2 where name = 'x'
  );
```

Comment: Hi mate,  assume that i want to sort by first updated date can I use something like min(date)

Comment: And you are combining with table2 only.  where is table1 ?

Comment: select SR.NAME, ML.DATE_LOGGED
FROM RULES SR
join LOG ML on ML.ENTITY_NAME=SR.NAME
WHERE ML.DATE_LOGGED=(
SELECT min(DATE_LOGGED) from LOG where ENTITY_NAME = 'x'
);

Comment: Looks good to me. You can post the `CREATE TABLE ...` statements, so I can test it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) table1.ID, table2.Num, table2.Name, table2.DATE
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.NAME = table2.NAME
WHERE table2.NAME = 'x'
ORDER BY table2.DATE ASC
```

**OR**

```
SELECT table1.ID, table2.Num, table2.Name, table2.DATE
FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM table2 WHERE NAME = 'x' ORDER BY DATE ASC) table2
     ON table1.NAME = table2.NAME
```

Comment: This solution works well, as long as there is a single row with the max date. If there are multiple, it randomly selects one of them.